# OnPostCreate in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using a `TextWatcher` in my Activity at the `onPostCreate` but now I have turned it into a Fragment.

What's the equivalent of this in a Fragment?

```
  @Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mSearchView.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: What do you intend to do?

Comment: well if i want to explain, when for example flipping the phone, Android recreates the activity, and the automatic restoration of the state of the input fields, is happening after onCreate had finished, where the TextWatcher was added as a TextChangedListener.The solution to the problem consisted in adding the TextWatcher in onPostCreate, which is called after restoration has taken place. so i need to add some thing like OnPostCreate in Activity to use in fragment

Comment: look at the fragment lifecycle and you will know your self. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html. `onActivityCreated`

Comment: dude, can you also help me what to replace 


  return ((ListViewActivity) mContext).new ListFilter();
 
 with, considering ListViewActivity is a fragment

Comment: Use `ListFragment` if you want a list in fragment. Fragment is attached to the Activity. sure i will post it as an answer

Comment: also http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPostCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29

Comment: well its not only a list, so i doubt that i can

Comment: i don't get it. What has that gotta do with list?

Comment: its for listviewfilter on textwatcher

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the Fragment Lifecycle. Wait until the Fragment is attached to the Activity

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

You can do your work in `onActivityCreated`.

To get `Context` use `getActivity()`

> `protected void onPostCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)`
>
> Added in API level 1
>
> Called when Activity start-up is complete (after `onStart()` and `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)` have been called). **Applications
>   will generally not implement this method; it is intended for system
>   classes to do final initialization after application code has run.**
>
> Derived classes must call through to the super class's implementation of this method. If they do not, an exception will be
>   thrown.
>
> Parameters `savedInstanceState`    If the Activity is being re-initialized after previously being shut down then this Bundle
>   contains the data it most recently supplied in
>   `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`. Note: Otherwise it is null.