# Navigation Drawer - what does syncState() do and why it should be called inside onPostCreate()?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I am learning to create navigation drawer in Android. While reading [this](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html), I can't understand following code:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

The documentation says:

> Synchronize the state of the drawer indicator/affordance with the
>   linked DrawerLayout.
>
> This should be called from your Activity's onPostCreate method to
>   synchronize after the DrawerLayout's instance state has been restored,
>   and any other time when the state may have diverged in such a way that
>   the ActionBarDrawerToggle was not notified. (For example, if you stop
>   forwarding appropriate drawer events for a period of time.)

Further I read about `onPostCreate()` from sstn's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221528/onpostcreate-in-fragment): [OnPostCreate in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221528/onpostcreate-in-fragment)

> onPostCreate() is mainly intented for framework use (although you can
>   override it). The docs say that it is called after onStart() and
>   onRestoreInstanceState().
>
> This might lead to the assumption that it might be called before
>   onResume() and thus probably before the message loop is dispatching
>   events (including AsyncTask's onPostExecute() method), meaning your
>   onPostExecute() will only fire after onPause().
>
> As onPostCreate() is not properly documented and not really intended
>   for application use - I might want to say it is not a good idea to
>   rely on any observed behaviour.

From these two I couldn't understand anything. What does `syncState()` exactly do and why it should be inside `onPostcreate()`? Can anyone explain it better?

Comment: It will synchronized the icon from the drawer and the drawer itself where when you move the drawer the icon rotate, try to remove the `syncState` and those animation wont work. I mean buggy

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin ya...I just noticed it...the animation isn't working when I comment this line...but hey, can you explain why it should be called within onPostCreate()?

Comment: As I said It needs to synchronized to enable the animation to work even if the activity has been restored and where to put it? the answer is the `onPostCreate` where it is called after the `onRestoreInstanceState`

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin i think you should post that as answer sir, its Bounty -(lifts eyebrows) :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, I think of this question as a good one. And I will collect this question and its answers. So, let's do some summaries here:

**First**, as to `ActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()`, just as the document says,

> Synchronize the state of the drawer `indicator/affordance` with the
>   linked `DrawerLayout`.
>
> This should be called from your `Activity`'s `onPostCreate` method to
>   synchronize after the `DrawerLayout`'s instance state has been
>   restored, and any other time when the state may have diverged in such
>   a way that the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` was not notified. (For example,
>   if you stop forwarding appropriate drawer events for a period of
>   time.)

**Second**, as to `Activity.onPostCreate(Bundle)`, **it is called when activity start-up is complete (after `onStart()` and `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)` have been called). Applications will generally not implement this method; it is intended for system classes to do final initialization after application code has run.**

But, *it is derived classes must call through to the super class's implementation of this method. If they do not, an exception will be thrown.*

So, **What does `syncState()` exactly do?**

Well, `ActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()` will synchronize the changed icon's state, which deponds on actions of `DrawerLayout`. If you ever tried to remove the `syncState()`, you will realize that the icon of arrow won't rotate any more.

And **why `syncState()` should be called inside `onPostcreate()`?**

Well, `onPostcreate()` is called when activity start-up is complete (after `onStart()` and `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)` have been called), while at the moment, `Activity` needs animations to be ready to work. So, if it isn't the best moment for animations, when is it?

Answer (score 13):

> what does syncState()

It will synchronize the drawer icon that rotates when the drawer is swiped gestured left or right and if you try to removed the `syncState()` the synchronization will fail thus resulting to buggy rotation or it wont even work.

> why it should be called inside onPostCreate()?

It is called in the `onPostCreate` to synchronize the animation all over again when the `Activity` is restored. The good thing about `onPostCreate` is that it is called right after `onRestoreInstanceState`

Edit:

As stated by @Vikram you can see the inline documentation of the method [`syncState`](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/support/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.java#291)

Comment: but what if you call if from `onResume()` ? that gets called before `onRestoreInstanceState` or it requires inputs from `onRestoreInstanceState` ??

Comment: @Elltz The `onResume` is called right after `onRestoreInstanceState` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()

Comment: @Elltz In addition to this, read the method comment here: [syncState()](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/support/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.java#291)

Comment: that actually sums all doubts, pretty clear answer thanks@Vikram

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `syncState()` from your activity's onPostCreate to set the state of the indicator (icon + drawer itself) based on whether the drawer layout is in open or closed state once the activity has been restored with `onRestoreInstanceState`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply say: SyncState() is to sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred. And call it in `onPostCreate(...)` is because of that `onPostCreate(...)` is called just after `onRestoreInstanceState(...)` is called.